# How to increase the size of the green box on a Word cover page?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm simply trying to increase the green box size on this cover page, right-clicking all the areas and tweaking the *Table Properties*, but no luck. Ideas? I’m sure it must be simple.

[image]

**Update:** After editing the footer size, it doesn't look like it's a footer(?).

[image]

**Update 2:** After adjusting the Table Row Height, the text simple moves further down. Even when increasing the area by dragging the white circle, there's no difference:

[image]

**Update 3:** Yet another requested image:

[image]

**Update 4:** Uploaded sample *.docx* [here](http://www64.zippyshare.com/v/B9vb6vVp/file.html).

Comment: Are you sure it is a table?. Maybe it's a footer?

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried changing the size as per the updated picture, but doesn't seem like it is?

Comment: [Adjusting Table Row Height](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T005981_Adjusting_Table_Row_Height.html)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I've tried that. There's a screenshot of what happens. Do you have Word? In 2016, this can be selected by the usual: _Insert > Cover Page_, and then _More Cover Pages from Office.com > Insight 2_.

Comment: No I don't have access to Word any more :/

Comment: It's still not clear what is the structure of that page and what you want to achieve. Could you please share a screenshot where non-printing characters are (CTRL+SHIFT+8) and table borders are visible? Also you complained that text moves down when you increase row height, this is the expected behaviour when text vertical alignment is bottom of cell.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Complained? When was I complaining? Also, like I said, it's very easy to choose the cover with: _Insert > Cover Page > More Cover Pages from Office.com > Insight 2_ (included by default). I've added the newest screenshot.

Comment: Sorry for my wording, I didn't want to be rude. I tried to reproduce the issue, but my company policy doesn't allow me to download content from office.com, could you create a file with this cover page and share it?

Comment: @MátéJuhász great, uploaded!

Comment: I tried the download link, but nothing downloads.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't get what you're saying. Did you visit the link and click the button, or just download the "link", or...? And also, like I've said before, this theme _(Insight 2)_, **has not** been downloaded from _office.com_. **It was installed by default**.

Comment: I visited the link and clicked the download button.  The button appears to point to a file when you hover but nothing downloaded.

Comment: @fixer1234 ok, do you need to download it?

Comment: I don't know if I'm the only one who had a problem with the download button, but at this point, looking at the actual file is probably the only way anybody will figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @fixer1234 did you read what I said about it?

Comment: You mean that it was installed by default?  Many of us don't have a recent version of Word, so no access to it.  Even if someone has a copy on their own computer, something could be corrupted in yours.  Without looking at the file, one guess would be that it's part of the background picture, so there is no separate element to resize.  In that case, you would need graphics tools to copy a portion of the green block and paste it higher, or sample the color, add a borderless frame where you want it, and fill with that color.